How can I locate the source file for a React modal in BigBlueButton for external video sharing?
I'm working on a development environment for BigBlueButton (BBB) and need to modify a modal that allows users to share external videos (from sources like YouTube or Vimeo) in a BBB meeting. Here’s what I’m facing:
What I've found so far:
In the browser console, I see the following HTML when the "Share an external video" modal is open:
<div id="simpleModal" class="ReactModal__Content ReactModal__Content--after-open ...">
  <header class="..."><h2>Share an external video</h2></header>
  <label for="video-modal-input">External Video URL</label>
  <input id="video-modal-input" name="video-modal-input" placeholder="Enter video URL" ... />
  <div id="external-video-note">Note: Shared external videos won’t be recorded. Supported sources include YouTube, Vimeo, ...</div>
  <button data-test="startNewVideo">Share new video</button>
</div>

What I need help with:
I need to identify the source file where this modal is defined. I suspect it might be a React component, possibly named something like VideoModal or similar, based on the modal's functionality.
Suggestions for a structured approach to locate unminified source files in BigBlueButton, particularly those related to UI components that Meteor bundles into production. Is there a specific path or naming convention used in BBB for such React components?
Environment: Ubuntu-based server running BBB and Meteor
Any help in locating this file or understanding how BBB organizes its React components would be greatly appreciated!
Where I’ve searched:
BigBlueButton server files - Specifically under /usr/lib/bigbluebutton and other likely paths for BBB’s UI code, but I couldn’t find any file directly linked to video-modal-input or external-video-note.
Meteor bundle directory - I ran a find command and located a minified JavaScript file at:
/usr/share/meteor/bundle/programs/web.browser/aafff60feb40ee701a9aa56832dbaabc299e5b6d.js


Opening this file in an editor, I saw minified React and JavaScript code, but due to its minification, it's challenging to trace specific components.

You mean this: https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton/blob/v3.0.0-beta.4/bigbluebutton-html5/imports/ui/components/external-video-player/external-video-player-graphql/modal/component.tsx#L82? FWIW all I did was search the GitHub repo for "VideoModal"

Thank you, @engineersmnky, for pointing me in the right direction.
Initially, my confusion stemmed from not realizing that the BBB frontend is bundled and served through Meteor, not realizing the frontend components were in a different structure entirely.
Thanks again for your help, this really cleared things up!
